# How can I seamlessly combine the two meshes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I tried using the Boolean modifier in a similar way that from what you can see if in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMLb5pTnwrg&ab_channel=Shift4cube) at 13:25 timestamp. However, I still have a noticeable edge rather than a curve-like blend, like you see if the second image, between the two pieces.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Meshes in edit mode:
[image]

Comment: Hi Skymero, you are talking about a video with timestamp - but there is no video. You are posting 2 pics, where i hardly see any connection. Please, improve your question to make it crystal clear, what you have (i think the upper picture) and what you wanna have (i think the lower, but i don't recognize a cylinder there!?). Also provide blend file so we can suggest solutions. I think it is also useful to provide a link of your video.

Comment: Always have in mind: you want a free solution in our spare time, so you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you and that it isn't necessary for us, to ask/clarify, what you really want.

Comment: please consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask thx.

Comment: You seem to have slipped up, and not provided a link to the video. Please include the link to the video, using the tools provided. then we'll have something to go on, and can re-open your post for you.

Comment: @RobinBetts I've added the video and I edited the images to show what specifically I'm trying to mimic.

Comment: @Skymero Could you attach an image of your mesh in Edit mode showing the topology after applying the boolean without the sub surface enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to (relatively) seamlessly combine two mesh parts,
first join the parts into one mesh object.

1. Make both part to have an open edge without a face.
2. Select both open edges.
3. Run the bridge tool.
4. Adjust bridge settings.
5. Potentially do some manual editing if the result isn't acceptable.
6. If your mesh parts weren't smooth to begin with, use auto smooth.

There are different bridge operators in Blender, built-in one does pretty much only a linear transition, and then there is the Loop Tools add-on, that comes with Blender, which has its own bridge tool. I recommend activating and trying it. It supports curved blend between joined edges.

If your mesh edges don't have a matching vertex/edge count, you'll end up having triangles in the fused area, but that usually isn't an issue for static meshes.

[image]